# How to convert set<obj, function> to set<obj>

Tags: c++, function, set

I have a container class called people that stores a set of person objects.
People takes in an std::function as one of set parameters.
this is used to define a custom comparator to sort the set.

is it possible to covert from

```
set<Person, std::function<bool(const Person &p1, const Person &p2)>>
```

to

```
set<Person>
```

A simplified version of the class is below

```
class People
{   
public :
    People() : people(compareByName()) {}
    void addPerson(Person p);
    set<Person> getPeople();

private:
    using PeopleSet = set<Person, std::function<bool(const Person &p1, const Person &p2)>>; // std::function for comparator type
    PeopleSet people;
};

set<Person> People::getPeople()
{
    return People;//Error Here (No sutable user defined conversion)
}
```

I want get people to return a `set<Person>` but am unsure how.

Comment: The second type parameter to a `set` is the sorting algorithm that the `set` uses to organize itself, so if you were to try and convert a `set` to another type of `set` with a different sorting algorithm (the default in this case would be `less<People>`, i.e., `person1 < person2`), I wouldn't necessarily expect to get the same set - it would be sorted differently. Is that what you intend to do - you want the same set sorted in a different way?

Comment: Yes I have a default Sort in the person class that it will revert too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is something like:

```
set<Person> People::getPeople()
{
    set<Person> reordered_set(original_set.begin(), original_set.end());
    return reordered_set;
}
```

In this case, you're creating an entirely new `set<Person>` by copying elements from the original set. I'm not sure whether you're okay with doing that copying or not.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I just done it myself by creating a new set and adding everything in a for each loop.

```
set<Person> People::getPeople()
{
    set<Person> peeps;
    for (Person const &p : people)
    {
        peeps.insert(p);
    }
    return peeps;
}
```

Comment: @Yakk why is it not C++?

Comment: you have blended in a little c#

Comment: For the same reason "bonjour" is not English?